# Adding Custom Font to Font List in XIB

Tags: ios, iphone

How can I add a custom font (by custom i mean, the font that dont exist in xcode) in font selector which comes through XIB?

I have added the font to the bundle and added it to the plist. I can use the font programmatically but I want to use it through XIB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode uses the fonts installed on the computer. Add the font to your `~/Library/Fonts` folder or double click the font and install it using Font Book.

The font selector in Xcode also allows you to type directly into it. I imagine you can type whatever font you want here and it will work at run time if the font is found, but to use it during development I'm pretty sure you need to have it installed.

[image]

Comment: I tried it but it is still not coming up there in the inspector where i intend it to be.

Comment: @SteveSmith they are under the font panel, not in the first drop down box that you get

Comment: @Daij-Djan where in Family? I am not getting it

Comment: @SteveSmith added a screenshot so you can see how to do it.

Comment: I am not able to edit anything in the font selector. Has anyone tested this in XCode 5 for iOS applications. The above screenshot seems to be  for a Mac App !

Comment: I also tried this, but every time i choose my font and deselect the element the system takes it back to the default font..

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a WYSIWYG preview of a custom font in Interface Builder, this isn't possible (even in Xcode 5).

Like you mentioned, you may continue to set the font programmatically.

Comment: I don't think so — I just opened Xcode 5 and couldn't get a preview for anything other than a system font. Even for user-installed fonts on OS X that appear for attributed text, the preview in IB doesn't update.

Comment: Custom fonts most definitely works in Xcode 5 for previewing controls. I'll post a screenshot when I'm not on mobile.

Comment: i confirm it too -- nice :)